# Finding out the amount of sessions for a particular event category in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I am getting a little confused as to what is the best way to measure the amount of sessions/visits for which a particular event has happened at least once.

I am reading different options for doing this: via segments or via filters. Which one is the correct one? I am getting different numbers!

In practice I have this section of my site that has these articles people can post and they tag their article with topics/tags. Using GTM I am collecting the topics/tags whenever someone views an article. So I have this event category named "Post view - topics" and in the event label I am listing the topics.

The idea is that I can build dashboards around specific topics (ex. the topic "*Analytics*") and track how many articles have been viewed, how many visits/sessions led to read an article that concerned that topic, what are the most popular articles for that topic, etc...

The way I've been doing it until now is:

- Apply a event-category filter on my data ("Post view - topics")
- Apply a event-label filter ("Analytics")

[screenshot of my filters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaKmN.png)

And then build my charts around that filtered data.

I thought this was the right way to do it, but now I'm concerned that this might not be correct, especially when I want to measure the amount of sessions. I am reading ([here for instance](https://help.analyticsedge.com/article/misunderstood-metrics-events/)) that it might be better to use segments?

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use segments, in this way you can request `sessions` which have your `event category` and your `event action`.

Comment: hey thanks Michele, I am going to give this a go

Comment: Let me know and mark answer as solved, please :)

Comment: Segments are the way to go in this scenario, thanks!
Using filters (instead of segments) over events to display users or sessions brings wrong values, seems like it counts a session/user multiple times when it interacted with multiple event..